# How to Solve "WebRtc hardware Codec driver not Installed" Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render

I am using Unity 2019. In that I am working on Render Streaming. When i try to run the project it says

Webrtc hardware codec driver not installed.

I have installed Directx11 . But  it is not working.

Could any one can help  suggest which driver i should install to run the webrtc.

thank

Answer (score -1):

You need the NVIDIA graphic board to use the hardware encoder.
You can ask technical questions on [the thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-render-streaming-introduction-faq.742481/) in this forum.